# Issue with negative sign after executing the tr command in UNIX

Tags: csv, unix

My requirement is to convert pipe separated file into normal excel.
So I used the below tr command in UNIX to perform this operation.
tr '|' ',' < filename.csv > filename_Final.csv
when I executed the above command it brings the negative sign of the field to field end.
So I tried to bring the negative sign to front of the field I dint find correct matching UNIX script.
If anyone come across a similar instance, kindly help.
Input: Pipe file

```
1|abc|-123
2|def|456
3|ijk|789
```

After tr execution

```
tr '|' ',' < filename.csv > filename_Final.csv
```

Output:
Pipe file is bifurcated into normal columns

```
1   abc 123-
2   def 456
3   ijk 789
```

My requirement is to bring the negative sign to front of the field.

Comment: That is weird, the minus sign is not part of the search- and replace-string. The output you show can't be the converted file since the separator should be comma but it looks like tabs. Is this after it has been imported? And when I run the same command I get -123.

Comment: I suspect you have some control characters in the file. What does `od -c filename.csv` reveal?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `tr`, you can just use `awk` to over-write the `Output-Field-Separator` which in your case is `|`

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' FS="|" OFS=" " filename.csv > filename_Final.csv
```

The above command over-writes the `OFS` to a single white-space, hence your input file

```
1|abc|-123
2|def|456
3|ijk|789
```

gets converted to

```
1 abc -123
2 def 456
3 ijk 789
```

thereby without disturbing the column entries present.

Comment: Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), since your problem is resolved now.

Comment: My requirement is to bring the negative sign to front of the field and to convert .csv into excel. Please help out on this

Comment: @Abirami: it is already in the front on the field, I wonder why you keep asking it.

Comment: Its bringing the negative sign to front but i need input .csv file with pipe extension to be converted to text to columns , means input file characters should be separated into each column as like in excel. This is my issue.